# pc.createanswer fails to execute

Tags: websocket, webrtc, sockjs, ice, rtcp

```
            // Set getUserMedia constraints
            var constraints = {video: true, audio: true};

            // From this point on, execution proceeds based on asynchronous events...
            // getUserMedia() handlers...
            var handleUserMedia= function (stream) {
                localStream = stream;
                attachMediaStream(localVideo, stream);
                console.log('Adding local stream.');
                sendMessage('got user media');
            }


            var handleUserMediaError= function (error){
                console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
            }


            // Server-mediated message exchanging...
            // 1. Server-->Client...
            // Handle 'created' message coming back from server:
            // this peer is the initiator
            var created =function  (){

                console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> Created");
                console.log('Created room ' );
                isInitiator = true;

                // Call getUserMedia() -- handleUserMedia()
                navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
                console.log('Getting user media with constraints', constraints);
                checkAndStart();
            }

            // Handle 'full' message coming back from server:
            // this peer arrived too late :-(
            var full= function  (){
                console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> Full");
                console.log('Room  is full');
            }

            // Handle 'join' message coming back from server:
            // another peer is joining the channel
            var join= function  (){
                console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> Join");
                console.log('Another peer made a request to join room ' );
                console.log('This peer is the initiator of room !');
                isChannelReady = true;
            }

            // Handle 'joined' message coming back from server:
            // this is the second peer joining the channel
            var joined= function  (){
                console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> Joined");
                console.log('This peer has joined room ');
                isChannelReady = true;
                // Call getUserMedia() --handleUserMedia()
                navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
                console.log('Getting user media with constraints', constraints);
            }

            // Server-sent log message...
            var log= function  (){
                console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> LOG");
                console.log.apply(console, array);
            }

            // Receive message from the other peer via the signaling server
            socket.onmessage = function(event){ 

                var payload = event.data.split( "\n" );
                var destinationurl = payload[1];
                var message = payload[7];
                /*message = message.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "");*/
                /*if(event.data.search("destination:/testurl")==-1)
                    {*/

                console.log('Received message:', message) ;

                if(message.search("created")!= -1) {
                    created();
                }
                else if(message.search("joined")!=-1) {
                    joined();
                }
                else if(message.search("join")!=-1) {

                    join();
                }

                else if (message.search("full")!=-1) {
                    full();
                }
                else if (message.search("got user media")!=-1) {
                    console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> Got User Media and Now Going to Call checkAndStart()");
                    checkAndStart();
                }
                else if (message.search("bye")!=-1 && isStarted) {
                    console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> BYE");
                    handleRemoteHangup();
                }
                else {
                    //message = message.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "");
                    //message= message.replace(/"/g, "'");
                    /*var obj = eval("(" + message + ')');*/
                    var message = message.substring(0, message.length-1)
                    message = JSON.parse(message);


                    if (message.type == 'offer') {
                        console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> OFFER, and will call CheckAndStart()");
                        if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
                            checkAndStart();
                        }
                        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
                        doAnswer();
                    }
                    else if (message.type == 'answer' && isStarted) {
                        console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> ANSWER, SETRemoteDescription");
                        pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
                    }
                    else if (message.type == 'candidate' && isStarted) {
                        console.log("--->>> Message From Server --->>> CANDIDATE");
                        var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({sdpMLineIndex:message.label,
                            candidate:message.candidate});
                        pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                    }
                }

            }
        /*}*/

            // 2. Client-->Server
            // Send message to the other peer via the signaling server
            var sendMessage=function (message){
                console.log('Sending message: ', message);
                /*socket.send(message);
                */


                //subscribe
                //send 
                //message create or join


                /*message = message.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, "");*/

                stomp.send("/createjoin",{},message);
            }

            // Channel negotiation trigger function
            var checkAndStart=function () {
                if (!isStarted && typeof localStream != 'undefined' && isChannelReady) {
                    createPeerConnection();
                    console.log("cehckAndStart Called, PeerConnection Created");
                    isStarted = true;
                    if (isInitiator) {
                        doCall();
                        console.log("cehckAndStart Called, Call initiated");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log("cehckAndStart Called, But call not initiated");
                }
            }

            // PeerConnection management...
            var createPeerConnection= function () {
                try {
                    pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(pc_config, pc_constraints);
                    pc.addStream(localStream);
                    pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
                    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection with:\n' + ' config: \'' + JSON.stringify(pc_config) + '\';\n' +' constraints: \'' + JSON.stringify(pc_constraints) + '\'.');
                } 
                catch (e) {
                    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
                    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
                    return;
                }

                pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
                pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;

                console.log("isInitiator: " + isInitiator);

                if (isInitiator) {
                    try {
                        // Create a reliable data channel
                        sendChannel = pc.createDataChannel("sendDataChannel",
                                {reliable: true});
                        console.log('Created send data channel');
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert('Failed to create data channel. ');
                        console.log('createDataChannel() failed with exception: ' + e.message);
                    }
                    sendChannel.onopen = handleSendChannelStateChange;
                    sendChannel.onmessage = handleMessage;
                    sendChannel.onclose = handleSendChannelStateChange;
                } 

                else { // Joiner
                    console.log("gotReceiveChannel\n\n\n\n\n");
                    pc.ondatachannel = gotReceiveChannel;
                }
            }

            // Data channel management
            var sendData= function  () {
                var data = sendTextarea.value;
                if(isInitiator) 

                    sendChannel.send(data);
                else receiveChannel.send(data);
                console.log('Sent data: ' + data);
            }

            // Handlers...
            var gotReceiveChannel = function (event) {
                console.log('Receive Channel Callback');
                receiveChannel = event.channel;
                receiveChannel.onmessage = handleMessage;
                receiveChannel.onopen = handleReceiveChannelStateChange;
                receiveChannel.onclose = handleReceiveChannelStateChange;
            }

            var handleMessage=function (event) {
                console.log('Received message: ' + event.data);
                receiveTextarea.value += event.data + '\n';
            }

            var handleSendChannelStateChange=function () {
                var readyState = sendChannel.readyState;
                console.log('Send channel state is: ' + readyState);

                // If channel ready, enable user's input
                if (readyState == "open") {
                    dataChannelSend.disabled = false;
                    dataChannelSend.focus();
                    dataChannelSend.placeholder = "";
                    sendButton.disabled = false;
                } 
                else {
                    dataChannelSend.disabled = true;
                    sendButton.disabled = true;
                }
            }

            var handleReceiveChannelStateChange=function () {
                var readyState = receiveChannel.readyState;
                console.log('Receive channel state is: ' + readyState);

                // If channel ready, enable user's input
                if (readyState == "open") {
                    dataChannelSend.disabled = false;
                    dataChannelSend.focus();
                    dataChannelSend.placeholder = "";
                    sendButton.disabled = false;
                } else {
                    dataChannelSend.disabled = true;
                    sendButton.disabled = true;
                }
            }

            // ICE candidates management
            var handleIceCandidate= function (event) {
                console.log('handleIceCandidate event: ', event);
                if (event.candidate) {
                    sendMessage(JSON.stringify({
                        type: 'candidate',
                        label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                        id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                        candidate: event.candidate.candidate}));
                } else {
                    console.log('End of candidates.');
                }
            }

            // Create Offer
            var doCall=function() {
                console.log('Creating Offer...');
                try {
                    pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, onSignalingError,
                            sdpConstraints);
                } catch (e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    console.log("error"+e);
                }
            }

            // Signaling error handler
            var onSignalingError= function (error) {
                console.log('Failed to create signaling message : ' + error.name);
            }

            // Create Answer
            var doAnswer= function() {
                console.log('Sending answer to peer.');

                    pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, onSignalingError,
                            sdpConstraints);

            }

            // Success handler for both createOffer()
            // and createAnswer()
            var setLocalAndSendMessage= function (sessionDescription) {
                console.log("sessionDescription**"+sessionDescription);
                pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
                sendMessage(JSON.stringify(sessionDescription));
            }

            // Remote stream handlers...
            var handleRemoteStreamAdded= function(event) {
                console.log('Remote stream added.');
                attachMediaStream(remoteVideo, event.stream);
                console.log('Remote stream attached!!.');
                remoteStream = event.stream;
            }

            var handleRemoteStreamRemoved= function (event) {
                console.log('Remote stream removed. Event: ', event);
            }

            // Clean-up functions...
            var hangup =function () {
                console.log('Hanging up.');
                stop();
                sendMessage('bye');
            }

            var handleRemoteHangup = function () {
                console.log('Session terminated.');
                stop();
                isInitiator = false;
            }
            var stop= function() {
                isStarted = false;
                if (sendChannel) sendChannel.close();
                if (receiveChannel) receiveChannel.close();
                if (pc) pc.close();
                pc = null;
                sendButton.disabled=true;
            }

            var attachMediaStream= function( video, lclStream)
            {
                if (window.URL) {
                    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(lclStream);
                } else {
                    video.src = lclStream;
                }
            }

   here is my message of type "offer"

{"sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4542862114432068298 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video data\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS vuXjLI4c8JwkOw4znUzYhl1Udp1q9zv63ZTn\r\nm=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 106 105 13 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Iom5FHfWBDWNB4O9\r\na=ice-pwd:ejEjHzkf0VDNR37sAomQVGjL\r\na=ice-options:google-ice\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:C1:56:A7:55:29:C7:5B:6D:BD:55:99:8E:40:B2:61:1C:78:F8:A4:8F:9B:95:D5:32:9C:BC:D0:A2:4B:EC:04\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=maxptime:60\r\na=ssrc:1321218595 cname:LMU99LT8oOlpgre0\r\na=ssrc:1321218595 msid:vuXjLI4c8JwkOw4znUzYhl1Udp1q9zv63ZTn ae0d1ec6-d144-43a7-998a-fe5de8137b21\r\na=ssrc:1321218595 mslabel:vuXjLI4c8JwkOw4znUzYhl1Udp1q9zv63ZTn\r\na=ssrc:1321218595 label:ae0d1ec6-d144-43a7-998a-fe5de8137b21\r\nm=video 1 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Iom5FHfWBDWNB4O9\r\na=ice-pwd:ejEjHzkf0VDNR37sAomQVGjL\r\na=ice-options:google-ice\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:C1:56:A7:55:29:C7:5B:6D:BD:55:99:8E:40:B2:61:1C:78:F8:A4:8F:9B:95:D5:32:9C:BC:D0:A2:4B:EC:04\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:video\r\na=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:116 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000\r\na=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:96 apt=100\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 2564084270 1462373314\r\na=ssrc:2564084270 cname:LMU99LT8oOlpgre0\r\na=ssrc:2564084270 msid:vuXjLI4c8JwkOw4znUzYhl1Udp1q9zv63ZTn 843026ff-14a0-4f3d-9306-13634fc9de15\r\na=ssrc:2564084270 mslabel:vuXjLI4c8JwkOw4znUzYhl1Udp1q9zv63ZTn\r\na=ssrc:2564084270 label:843026ff-14a0-4f3d-9306-13634fc9de15\r\na=ssrc:1462373314 cname:LMU99LT8oOlpgre0\r\na=ssrc:1462373314 msid:vuXjLI4c8JwkOw4znUzYhl1Udp1q9zv63ZTn 843026ff-14a0-4f3d-9306-13634fc9de15\r\na=ssrc:1462373314 mslabel:vuXjLI4c8JwkOw4znUzYhl1Udp1q9zv63ZTn\r\na=ssrc:1462373314 label:843026ff-14a0-4f3d-9306-13634fc9de15\r\nm=application 1 DTLS/SCTP 5000\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Iom5FHfWBDWNB4O9\r\na=ice-pwd:ejEjHzkf0VDNR37sAomQVGjL\r\na=ice-options:google-ice\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 0B:C1:56:A7:55:29:C7:5B:6D:BD:55:99:8E:40:B2:61:1C:78:F8:A4:8F:9B:95:D5:32:9C:BC:D0:A2:4B:EC:04\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:data\r\na=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024\r\n","type":"offer"}


My pc is like: iceConnectionState: "new"
iceGatheringState: "new"
localDescription: null
onaddstream: function (event) {
ondatachannel: function (event) {
onicecandidate: function (event) {
oniceconnectionstatechange: null
onnegotiationneeded: null
onremovestream: function (event) {
onsignalingstatechange: null
remoteDescription: RTCSessionDescription
signalingState: "have-remote-offer"
__proto__: RTCPeerConnection
```

All the methods associated with these events are getting attached correctly. Offer is created and messages exchanged but after remote stream attached executes everything stops. There are no answer type messages exchanged. Moreover createanswer doesn't execute any of the callbacks. Neither success nor error. All the errors are correctly formed.

```
Please suggest why its not executing.
```

Comment: does the `if(message.type == 'offer')` ever return true? Is `checkAndStart` actually called in that block?

Comment: Yeah it returns true checkAndStart is called peer 1 send offer to peer 2, peer 2 receives message attaches remote stream but doesnt send answer to peer 1.